# Eclipselink update existing tables

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

Maybe I got it wrong but i though that JPA was able to update an existing table (model changed adding a column) but is not working in my case.

I can see in the logs eclipselink attempting to create it but failing because it already exists. Instead of trying an update to add the column it keeps going.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jwrestling"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="org.eclipse.persistence.logging.DefaultSessionLog"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
```

And here's the table with the change (online column added)

```
[EL Warning]: 2010-05-31 14:39:06.044--ServerSession(16053322)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.0.v20100517-r7246): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'account' already exists
Error Code: 1050
Call: CREATE TABLE account (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, USERNAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, SECURITY_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, EMAIL VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, STATUS VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, TIMEDATE DATETIME NOT NULL, PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ONLINE TINYINT(1) default 0 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE account (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, USERNAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, SECURITY_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, EMAIL VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, STATUS VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, TIMEDATE DATETIME NOT NULL, PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ONLINE TINYINT(1) default 0 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
[EL Warning]: 2010-05-31 14:39:06.074--ServerSession(16053322)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.0.v20100517-r7246): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

After this it continues with the following.

Am I doing something wrong or is a bug?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of EclipseLink 2.4, you can use this in the specification of your persistence unit:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behavior when using the `create-tables` value. From the documentation about the `eclipselink.ddl-generation` property:

> #### [Using EclipseLink JPA Extensions for Schema Generation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_for_Schema_Generation)
>
> The following are the valid values for
>   the use in a `persistence.xml`  file:
>
> - `none` – EclipseLink does not generate DDL; no schema is generated.
> - `create-tables` – EclipseLink will attempt to execute a `CREATE TABLE`
>     SQL for each table. If the table
>     already exists, EclipseLink will
>     follow the default behavior of your
>     specific database and JDBC driver
>     combination (when a `CREATE TABLE` SQL
>     is issued for an already existing
>     table). In most cases an exception is
>     thrown and the table is not created.
>     EclipseLink will then continue with
>     the next statement. (See also
>     [`eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name).)
> - `drop-and-create-tables` – EclipseLink will attempt to `DROP` all
>     tables, then `CREATE` all tables. If
>     any issues are encountered,
>     EclipseLink will follow the default
>     behavior of your specific database and
>     JDBC driver combination, then continue
>     with the next statement. (See also
>     [`eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name)
>     and
>     [`eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name).)

So you might want `drop-and-create-tables` instead.

Comment: I want to keep my current data. Is there any way of updating existing tables (alter statements). No equivalent to hibernate's update option?

Comment: @javydreamercsw I'm not aware of a direct equivalent.

Comment: @PascalThivent this is an old one, but look at the accepted answer. They seem to have added it after your answer. You might want to update it.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate JPA implementation does exactly what you want. Here is the property that enables that behaviour:

```
property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"
```

Comment: I'm aware of that but I was hoping for something in standard JPA and/or JPA2

Comment: I realized that in real life, i do not need to update tables. If i am still developing , then i can always drop and create the table. if the table has data and i dont want to drop it, its a better practice to change the tables myself. This is mostly in live environment where i dont want tables to be updated automatically.

Comment: @joshua: Actually, there are solutions for updating the DB structure even on a live system, but they are external to JPA/Hibernate. One solution is Google Flyway (http://code.google.com/p/flyway/); or google for "database versioning", "database migration".

Comment: Flyway looks interesting. Added to my tools. Thanks! Make that an answer and you should be the one I pick.

Answer (score 0):

create-or-extend-tables does the trick